# MySQL create table select entries with column=null if exist else another appropriate entry

Tags: mysql, sql

```
create table if not exists table1
    (key ind_name(some_id))
    select *
    from table0
    group by some_id;

if (there is an appropriate entry with column1 NULL) : select it
else : select any another appropriate entry
```

I would appreciate your help cause I'm confused on how to write this in MySQL.

UPDATE: I ended up creating a table table0_temp with entries ordered the way I want and then using it in the query above.

```
create
temporary table if not exists table0_temp
    select * from table0
        order by column1 asc;
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. Can you show a few rows of sample data and the desired result? Please [edit] your question to show that stuff.

Comment: you can use `CASE` condition  like check is value is `case when condition is null then data else other data`

Comment: it's like or with priority. NULL or anything. But entries with column=NULL have higher priority.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are asking but I guess you are searching the following:

```
SELECT COALESCE(orphan_code ,'appropriate entry');
```

COALESCE will return orphan_code if it is not null, otherwise it will return 'appropriate entry'.